# What is the advante when we use dynamically created component instead of ngif directive?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following component

```
<app-modal/>
```

so if i want to insert it dynamically into the DOM i use ngIf directive

```
<app-modal *ngIf="condition" />
```

I know that in angular we can also insert some component dynamically into the DOM through `resolveComponentFactory` and `createComponent` methods.

like explained here
https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d

I wonder is there advante or disatvantage in both cases ?
The only thing i found is that `ngOnChanges` is not fired in dynamically created components

https://indepth.dev/posts/1054/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular#ngonchanges

Comment: `*ngIf` is more of a conditional use case where you need to show a particular component based on some data or flag. For example, show error component, which shows list of errors based on error flag. Where as dynamic components are generally for use cases  where you need create components on the fly/runtime. For example, you have list of ad components but not sure until some parameters come in. Based on that parameter, you instantiate a ad component. Each have their advantages, which depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost always more convenient to use `*ngIf`

Creating components dynamically is for the case that you don't know what component you will be rendering or there are multiple possible options.